# Meteor cannot add package iron router: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'match'

Tags: javascript, meteor, web-applications, iron-router

I'm working on a simple web application project and need to add iron router package to Meteor. The input is:

```
meteor add iron:router
```

However, I've got

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'match'
```

I have successfully added other packages before this one. So I'm confused about this failure. Could anyone help me?

Comment: ps: I'm using Meteor 1.2.1 and running it in Mac's Terminal.

Comment: I've this error on a old project. To fix that, I specify the version `0.9.0` for `iron:router` package. Maybe it will help you.